# using UrlRewriteFilter not redirecting properly

Tags: tomcat, redirect, url-rewriting, urlrewriter

This is my

```
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
      <name>Canonical Hostnames</name>
      <condition name="host" operator="equal">^example\.com</condition>
      <condition name="host" operator="notequal">^$</condition>
      <from>^/(.*)</from>
      <to type="redirect" last="true">http://www.example.com/$1</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

It is redirectiing well to `www.example.com` but the problem is `http://example.com/resetpassword/?user=2560256&token=1233` is redirected to `http://example.com/resetpassword`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To preserve the query string, you can add the `use-query-string` parameter to the `urlrewrite` element as follows:

```
<urlrewrite use-query-string="true">
```

Alternatively, you can include the query string in your redirect URL as follows:

```
<to type="redirect" last="true">http://www.example.com/$1?%{query-string}</to>
```

See the documentation [here](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/4.0/index.html).